# JobRestartException: JobInstance already exists and is not restartable

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

I'm using Spring Batch with Spring cloud tasks. I have the following configuration in my job:

```
@Bean
    public Job jobDemo(
            @Value("${jobname}")String jobName,
            JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
            JobCompletionNotificationListener listener
        ) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .preventRestart()
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(stepA())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
```

I don't want the restart functionality in the job, that's why I have put `.preventRestart()`. I want to launch a new job every time the task runs, that is, a new instance of the job to run even when the last time the job has failed or stopped or anything. But I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRestartException: JobInstance already exists and is not restartable
```

This happens only in the scenarios when the job does not finish sucessfully. Any ideas about the solution?

Comment: I assume you're executing this via Spring Boot?

Comment: @MichaelMinella yes! So when we just start the task, the batch also starts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JobInstance` can only be completed once successfully.  When you are starting a Spring Batch job via Spring Boot, Spring Batch handles the logic to increment a `JobParameter` if there is a `JobParametersIncrementer` provides (as you have).  However...when Spring Batch does that incrementing, it only increments if the previous job was successful.  In your case, you want it to always increment.  Because of that, you're going to need to write your own `CommandLineRunner` that always increments the `JobParameters`.

Spring Boot's `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner` is where the code to launch a job exists.  You'll probably want to extend that and override it's `execute` method to be sure job parameters are always incremented.

Comment: Yeap. I changed my code. But not added JobLauncherCommandLineRunner, added my own implementation of paras incrementer. I noted that the previous one was giving the behaviour as you mentioned. Is that also fine, right?